# Rotating SCNNode on Y Axis Based on Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have a model which I rotate using the pan gesture. It works fine but it does not rotate all 360 degrees. It rotates to 180 and then stops. Also if I end the pan gesture and starts again then the position is reset. Here is my code.

```
 @objc func panned(recognizer :UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        var newAngleY :Float = 0.0

        if recognizer.state == .changed {

            let sceneView = recognizer.view as! ARSCNView
            let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: sceneView)

            print(translation.x)

            let scnHitTestResults = self.sceneView.hitTest(touchPoint, options: nil)

            if let hitTestResult = scnHitTestResults.first {

                let chairNode = hitTestResult.node

                newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(Double.pi)/180
                newAngleY += chairNode.eulerAngles.y/180
                chairNode.eulerAngles.y = newAngleY
            }
        }

        else if recognizer.state == .ended {
            currentAngleY = newAngleY
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

Create a `var currentAngleY: Float = 0.0`

Then in your PanGestureRecognizer try the following:

```
/// Rotates An Object On It's YAxis
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
@objc func rotateObject(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let nodeToRotate = currentNode else { return }

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view!)
    var newAngleY = (Float)(translation.x)*(Float)(Double.pi)/180.0
    newAngleY += currentAngleY

    nodeToRotate.eulerAngles.y = newAngleY

    if(gesture.state == .ended) { currentAngleY = newAngleY }
}
```

`nodeToRotate` refers to an SCNNode I have already selected, but you should be able to adapt it as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that also same result. It does not rotate all 360 degrees. It rotates half way and when I try to rotate again it resets the position again.

Comment: I would suggest trying the function on a simple SCNode with a Box geometry and seeing if that works (which it does for my Nodes). It could be an issue with the actual model itself and how it is rendered e.g whether it’s a child node etc. Try the box example and then have a look at the chair :)

Comment: Also did you put the variable at the top of your class and not in the function method body?

Comment: You are right! It does work with the Cube.. So def issue with the model and how it is rendered. Thanks for the help! I believe this has something to do with the pivot of the model because when the model rotates it looks like its center is off.